# First TreeViewColumn is not rendering

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade, gtktreeview

I have an window defined in a gtk-builder file made with Glade. It contains a `gtk.Window`, with a child `gtk.TreeView` with 2 `gtk.TreeViewColumn`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.20"/>
    <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="bookmarks_window">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="events">GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK | GDK_STRUCTURE_MASK</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes">Bookmarks</property>
        <property name="modal">True</property>
        <property name="default_width">350</property>
        <property name="default_height">200</property>
        <property name="destroy_with_parent">True</property>
        <property name="type_hint">menu</property>
        <property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="bookmarks_scroll">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="hscrollbar_policy">never</property>
            <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeView" id="bookmarks_tree">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="events">GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK | GDK_STRUCTURE_MASK</property>
                <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
                <property name="headers_clickable">False</property>
                <property name="rules_hint">True</property>
                <property name="fixed_height_mode">True</property>
                <property name="show_expanders">False</property>
                <property name="enable_grid_lines">vertical</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="line_column">
                    <property name="sizing">fixed</property>
                    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Line</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="text_column">
                    <property name="sizing">fixed</property>
                    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Text</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

I'm creating the window doing:

```
def show_window(parent_window):
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("mywindow.ui")

    window = builder.get_object('bookmarks_window')
    window.set_transient_for(parent_window)

    tree = builder.get_object('bookmarks_tree')
    tree.set_search_column(1)

    store = gtk.TreeStore(int, str)
    for i in xrange(1, 6):
        store.append((i, "Line {}".format(i)))
    tree.set_model(store)

    line_renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    line_column = builder.get_object('line_column')
    line_column.pack_start(line_renderer)
    line_column.set_attributes(line_renderer, text=0)

    text_renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    text_column = builder.get_object('text_column')
    text_column.pack_start(text_renderer)
    text_column.set_attributes(text_renderer, text=1)

    window.show_all()
```

This will only show the "Text" column:

```
+---------------+
| Line 1        |
| Line 2        |
| Line 3        |
| Line 4        |
| Line 5        |
+---------------+
```

If I change the order of the `gtk.TreeViewColumn`s in the interface file from:

```
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="line_column">...</object>
</child>
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="text_column">...</object>
</child>
```

to:

```
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="text_column">...</object>
</child>
<child>
  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="line_column">...</object>
</child>
```

Only the "Line" column will display:

```
+---------------+
| 1             |
| 2             |
| 3             |
| 4             |
| 5             |
+---------------+
```

But I want it to look like:

```
+---+-----------+
| 1 | Line 1    |
| 2 | Line 2    |
| 3 | Line 3    |
| 4 | Line 4    |
| 5 | Line 5    |
+---+-----------+
```

Changing the order of the `gtk.TreeViewColumn`s in the interface file is changing what column is displayed, which doesn't make sense to me. It's always hiding the first column. Does anyone know what I am missing or overlooking? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set column sizing mode to "fixed" (I assume you need this for performance reasons), yet do not set `fixed-width` property. Set it to any value on both columns and they will appear.